# Performance of Eigen Solver in Eigen lib

Tags: c++, matrix, eigenvector, eigen3

I just download the latest Eigen lib version.

and The Eigen solver have anotations (o) n^3..generally same like matrix multiplication

S, why if I have 500*500 matrix the time of computing EVD is about 15-30 
seconds..and MAtrix matrix multiply about 10 seconds...

And in case about 2450*2450 size of matrix the EVD TIME is about 35! Minutes!

And the TIME of matrix matrix multiply is about 65 secnods!

```
 LOGD( "This isf beging EVD  matA ");
    if(matA.cols()>2000){
        Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXd> esSelf(DATA);
        D =esSelf.eigenvalues().asDiagonal();
        matV =esSelf.eigenvectors();
    }else{

        EigenSolver<MatrixXd> ess0(DATA);
        D = ess0.pseudoEigenvalueMatrix();
        matV = ess0.pseudoEigenvectors();

    }
    LOGD( "This isf END EVD  matA ");
```

Comment: I don't know the specifics but o(n^3) is a very costly algorithm.

Comment: Both are O(n^3), that's true (just keep in mind that the Landau notation suppresses constant factors). But the Eigen solver is behaving entirely different from a Matrix multiplication in terms of memory access patterns and cache locality. The matrix multiplication scales almost perfectly with large matrices, whereby computing the EVD suffers from cache misses once matrix size passes ~1-2k.

Comment: Do you compile with optimizations turned on? Like parallel processing with OpenMP `-f openmp`, speed `-O3`, release `-DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG`? Those are flags for g++/clang++, not sure the corresponding ones for VC.

Comment: See http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Benchmark for benchmarks. The tests were performed on a CPU with 32kB L1 cache, and you can clearly see where this became insufficient. In order to compute EVD for larger matrices, you **NEED** a CPU which has a larger L1 cache, otherwise you will be limited severely by L1 misses and you won't be able to utilize the FPU properly. There is no other way to speed up the calculation of the EVD.

Comment: U have right : I Found this :https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=111782

Comment: But I dont need genrealized self Adjoint..

Comment: @user2165656 This may now sound weird, but if you can be sure that 2450*2450 is the biggest matrix you will have to solve,  go for an old AMD Phenom II CPU. They feature 64kB L1 cache and can therefor solve about 1.5-2.0x larger matrices before they suffer the same slow down. If you are planing on going even larger - bad luck, there is no x86 CPU I'm aware of which would be suited.

Comment: Given your timing you clearly forgot to enable compiler optimizations (e.g., -O2).  Expect a 100x speedup doing so.